# A complete catchup of the testnet keeps failing on verifying ledger

Tags: stellar-core, testnet, ledger, docker

Trying to perform a full sync on the Stellar testnet using a recent dockerized stellar/quickstart in persistent mode (`horizon: v0.13.1, core: v9.2.0, docker: v18.06.0-ce`). After around 10 hours the ledger files were downloaded:

```
2018-08-19T08:58:22.998 GAFH2 [History INFO] Catching up: downloading ledger files 137/137 (100%)
2018-08-19T08:58:23.117 GAFH2 [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 10618370 : {"agree":3,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"273af2","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}
2018-08-19T08:58:23.125 GAFH2 [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=10618372, prev=14f667, tx_count=2, sv: [  txH: 3c047b, ct: 1534669102, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2018-08-19T08:58:23.555 GAFH2 [History INFO] Catchup verifying ledger chain for checkpointRange [10609663..10618354]
2018-08-19T08:58:23.560 GAFH2 [History INFO] Catching up: verifying checkpoint 1/136 (0%)
```

But for some reason failed verification:

```
2018-08-19T08:58:23.566 GAFH2 [History ERROR] Catchup material failed verification - unsupported ledger version, propagating failure [VerifyLedgerChainWork.cpp:252]
2018-08-19T08:58:23.567 GAFH2 [Ledger ERROR] Error catching up: Connection timed out [LedgerManagerImpl.cpp:536]
2018-08-19T08:58:23.568 GAFH2 [Ledger ERROR] Catchup will restart at next close. [LedgerManagerImpl.cpp:537]
2018-08-19T08:58:23.569 GAFH2 [Ledger INFO] Changing state LM_CATCHING_UP_STATE -> LM_BOOTING_STATE
2018-08-19T08:58:23.571 GAFH2 [Work WARNING] WorkManager got FAILURE_FATAL from catchup
```

Before retrying, I stopped stellar-core, and ran:

```
$ stellar-core --newhist cache
$ stellar-core --newdb
$ stellar-core --forcescp
$ stellar-core
```

Even the next time the catchup material failed verification. I was using the following config:

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-testnet1.stellar.org",
"core-testnet2.stellar.org",
"core-testnet3.stellar.org"]

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=localhost user=stellar password=********"
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true

#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51 # rounded up -> 2 nodes out of 3
VALIDATORS=[
"GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
"GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
"GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]

[HISTORY.cache]
get="cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /opt/stellar/history-cache/{1}"

#The history store of the Stellar testnet
[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Please let me know, how to solve this issue, as I need the complete catchup to query the SQL (finding holders of specific assets etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 9.2 does not support version 10 of the protocol.

You can import a subset of the historical data (with command line catch-up), install the latest release candidate (10.0.0rc2 labeled "testing" in the quickstart image) or wait for a stable build (should be out in the next couple weeks).