# Catching up stellar-core ledger can't be synched

Tags: stellar-core

I keep getting this error after the initial download of ledger files has caught up. After this error, it attempts to re-download the ledger files.

```
2018-08-27T13:04:12.199 GDU4N [History ERROR] Catchup material failed verification - unsupported ledger version, propagating failure [VerifyLedgerChainWork.cpp:252]
2018-08-27T13:04:12.199 GDU4N [Ledger ERROR] Error catching up: Connection timed out [LedgerManagerImpl.cpp:536]
2018-08-27T13:04:12.199 GDU4N [Ledger ERROR] Catchup will restart at next close. [LedgerManagerImpl.cpp:537]
2018-08-27T13:04:12.200 GDU4N [Ledger INFO] Changing state LM_CATCHING_UP_STATE -> LM_BOOTING_STATE
2018-08-27T13:04:12.203 GDU4N [Work WARNING] WorkManager got FAILURE_FATAL from catchup
2018-08-27T13:04:38.331 GDU4N [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
```

I'm using the [SDF packages](https://github.com/stellar/packages#sdf---packages).

I tried to `docker pull stellar/quickstart:testing` like [this solution](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/a-complete-catchup-of-the-testnet-keeps-failing-on-verifying-ledger), but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jbrejcha mentioned, it looks like you are trying to connect to Tesnet using version 9 of the protocol.

The official unstable repository contains the Release Candidates, these are marked `-rc`.

It is worth mentioning that the SDF recommends you only use these packages in testing and stick to the stable repository for your production environments.

Follow [these](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/README.md#bleeding-edge-unstable-repository) instructions to add the [SDF unstable](https://apt.stellar.org/public/unstable/) repository, you will then be able to install a V10 release candidate:

`apt-get update && apt-get install stellar-core=10.0.0rc2-16`

Once version `10.0.0` is officially released the package will be available in the stable repository.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I updated stellar-core to v10 the sync is now working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are still running version 9 of stellar-core. When opening `http://localhost:11626/info` you should see `"build" : "v10.0.0rc2",`
in the upper part of the screen.

If not, you need to specify the "testing" option when running docker, such as: `docker run --rm -d -p "8000:8000" -p "5432:5432" -p "11626:11626" -p "11625:11625" -v "/Users/myaccount/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart:testing --testnet`

Otherwise you would still be running the original stellar/quickstart package.

Comment: Yes thanks for respond. As you said its because mine still v9. I updated to v10 and now its working